# ¿Por qué se me sustituyen los elementos del array?

Tags: php, sql

Estoy realizando un programa que saca información de una base de datos, lo agrega a una clase y dicha clase la inserto dentro de un array:

```
$sql2="SELECT* FROM dbo.Usuarios";
$users= new usuario();
$userss= array();
$result2=sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2 );
while($row2= sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $users->construirusuario($row2['ID'], 
    $row2['Uss'],$row2['Pass'],$row2['Email'], $row2['Tlf'],$row2['Nombre']);
    $userss[]=$users;  

}
```

El problema viene cuando muestro el resultado de dicho array mediante un `foreach()`, y es que me dice que todos los elementos del array son como el último que se insertó, es decir, yo inserto un coche 1, coche2 y coche3 y cuando saco el contenido en vez de mostrarme esa secuencia me muestra:

```
coche3,coche3,coche3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `$users`, es un `objeto` y al guardarla en el arreglo `$userss`, lo que se guarda en realidad es la referencia al `objeto` y no el valor del `objeto`.

Soluciones:

- Crear una nueva instancia de `usuario` dentro del bucle `foreach`

  ```
  while($row2= sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $users = new usuario();
      $users->construirusuario($row2['ID'], $row2['Uss'],$row2['Pass'],$row2['Email'], $row2['Tlf'],$row2['Nombre']);
      $userss[]=$users;  
  }
  ```
- En lugar de guardar el `objeto`, guardar, por ejemplo, la representación del mismo como `arreglo`

  ```
  while($row2= sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $users->construirusuario($row2['ID'], $row2['Uss'],$row2['Pass'],$row2['Email'], $row2['Tlf'],$row2['Nombre']);
      $userss[]= (array) $users; // Suponiendo que los datos que se imprimen son propiedades públicas.
  }
  ```

Comment: @Jose, para una respuesta mas acertada, sería necesario que agregues en tu pregunta la definición de la clase `usuario`